# Compute the directional derivative $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (A+tX)^{-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis

The invertible $n \times n$ matrices constitute an open set $U\subseteq Mat(n\times n)$.
Given linear mappings that the inversion mapping inv: $U\rightarrow Mat(n\times n)$ is differentiable, compute the directional
derivative $\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (A+tX)^{-1}$ when $A\in U$ and $X\in Mat(n\times n)$.

Theorem: If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then the directional derivative, $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(a+tv)$, exists and equals $(Df)(a)v$.

Given this theorem I am trying to figure out exactly what I am to do in this problem. Do I find the inverse of the matrix $A+tX$ and then take the derivative with respect to $t$?

Comment: Hint: Try to compute the derivative of $I_n = (A+tX)(A+tX)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f(X)=X^{-1}$ 
at $I$ is $Df_I(U)=-U$ since for $\|h\|<1$, $(I+h)^{-1}=\sum_n (-1)^nh^n$. Write $A+tX= (I+tXA^{-1})A$, $(A+tX)^{-1} = A^{-1}(I+tXA^{-1})^{-1}$,

so ${d\over{dt}}(A+tX)^{-1}=-A^{-1}XA^{-1}$.

Comment: why is the derivative of $f$ given by $D_{I}(U)=-U$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof using directional derivatives. I understand that this post is old, but I hope someone may still find it useful. Denote $f(A)=A^{-1}$ so that
$$f(A + tX) \cdot (A + tX) = \mathrm{Id}.$$
Differentiate with respect to $t$ and use the product rule to get
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} f(A + tX) \cdot (A + tX) + f(A + tX) \cdot X = 0.$$
Then plug in $t=0$ and recall the definition of $f$ to obtain
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} f(A + tX) \bigg|_{t=0} \cdot A + A^{-1} X = 0.$$
It follows that
$$Df(A)X = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} f(A + tX) \bigg|_{t=0} = - A^{-1} X A^{-1}.$$